# Append a word between empty element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can by jquery know that if between a element is empty append between same element word "there is not"?

```
<div>Ok</div>
<div>No</div>
<div></div> // i want append between this div "there is not" that is empty. Like: <div>there is not</div>
<div>Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try -

```
$("div:empty").append("there is not");
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/St8sV/

Answer (score 0):

[More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590032/apend-a-word-between-element-empty/7590054#7590054) verbose form:

```
$('div').each(function() {
   if ($(this).html() == '') {
      $(this).html('there is not');
   }
}
```